# Vertical centering in React Native doesn't work

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I use a `ScrollView` and I am not able to center an icon in one of inner `View`s.

[image]

```js
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

<ScrollView>
...
        <View style={styles.detailRowContainer}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={styles.label} numberOfLines={1}>
              {'Phone Number'}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.value} numberOfLines={1}>
              {phone}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.round}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onPressPhone}>
              <Icon size={22} name="phone" />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </View>;
...
</ScrollView>



        detailRowContainer: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            flex: 1,
            marginTop: 10,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: Colors.lightGray,
        },
        label: {
            color: Colors.glofoxDark,
            marginBottom: 3,
        },
        value: {
            color: Colors.glofoxDark,
            fontWeight: '800',
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: Colors.lightGray,
        },
        round: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            borderRadius: 30,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            padding: 4,
        },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The styles need to be modified in this way.

Right now you're doing

- `flexDirection: row` along `justifyContent: center`. Since your first child element is taking complete **parent flex**, therefore it does not show its effect
- `paddingBottom` is given but , for centering an equivalent `paddingTop` must be given
- `padding` for the round style should be replaced with `margin`, otherwise it affects the position of the inner elements
- `alignItems` in round , must not be `flex-end`, it should be replaced with `center`

Here are the styles that will fix the vertical centering

```js
 detailRowContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 10,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: Colors.lightGray,
    },

 round: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        borderRadius: 30,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 4
    },
```

Comment: if I change padding like this, icon wrapper position is [the same as before](https://i.imgur.com/kQmR0A6.png) and icon is [not centered](https://i.imgur.com/s6vguLt.png)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. I didn't know padding can impact position of inner elements